# Creating Application/Virtual Directories in a site that POINT to that site to simulate multiple sites. Good idea?

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

We need a way to say

www.site.com/india
www.site.com/asia
www.site.com/usa
  etc...

But we want all these requests to point back to www.site.com and not have to physically create the files and directories for every type of site... so if I just create a virtual directory (www.site.com/india) and point it to www.site.com... then I figure I can look at the URL and set some parameters/text/images accordingly to fill out the template...

Does this make sense?  Or are there issues with web.configs ? OR a better way

Comment: I should have mentioned.. this is for using with the Ektron CMS. Ektron CMS is a web forms ASP.NET...  So how easy it is to change a web forms app to use routing ?   I ma wondering maybe it is not complex to just use the routing aspect from MVC without using MVC?

Comment: oops.. I just noticed you gave an example of routing in webforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would encourage you to consider Routing, as demonstrated here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

The given sample, repeated here so you can (hopefully) see the relevance, is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

By similar methods, you can merely extract the information you need

---

The first example was for MVC Routing, to do webforms routing you should look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(VS.90).aspx and here's a (very limited) example:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add("BikeSaleRoute", new Route
    (
       "bikes/sale", 
       new CustomRouteHandler("~/Contoso/Products/Details.aspx")
    ));
}
```

Using a custom routehandler that they build in the code. Routehandlers are easy to use, once you get the hang of it. And they allow you more expressiveness.

Comment: Downvoting for copy-pasting the default routing configuration of an ASP.NET MVC application without any adaptation to the original question about classic ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: @drachenstern, sure he did. Don't you read the tags? They are very informative. There's the [`asp.net`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) tag and the [`asp.net-mvc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) tag on this site which are quite different. The OP properly tagged his question.

Comment: @punkouter notice indeed that my post reverted to MVC instead of webforms. There are ways to do routing in webforms, but the MVC style will be simpler to maintain in the long run, at least according to popular theory ;)

Comment: @Punkouter ~ A note for you while you're learning the SO community: prefix a username (at least 5 or 6 letters) with the @ sign as I have done to cause that user to be notified that you are talking to them. It shows up on the SuperMultiCollider in the top left hand corner too, making for easier notification.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that localizing the same site five ways without having different  web.configs pointing you to your localization files will be difficult.

What I would do is have www.site.com's index wither automatically discover the client's location or ask them what version of the site they want. Then, refer them to a default.aspx under that site's virtual directory, that uses a common set of your custom web controls, localized according to the resource file referenced in that site's web.config. That way, all you'll need to copy is the site skeleton, which can be as little as the index.aspx.

If the site is mostly aspxs, this isn't going to work as well. In that case, I would do the website selection as before, but use a query string to keep track of client location and thus localization. That should still allow you to bring up the correct localization settings.

Comment: Are you saying that the virtual directories should point to unique copies of the site each with a seperate web.config? Whatever happened to DRY? If all the VDs point at the same absolute path, how are you intending to apply different web configs?

Comment: I wasn't saying either of those things. The VDs would point to subdirectories of the site, which would each have their own Global.asax and web.config pointing them to site-specific localization based on a culture indicated by the VD. They MAY need their own default.aspx files, but I doubt they'd even need that.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I have to admit it wouldn't be my first approach as you still need directory-per-country which seems a little clunky - especially since some OSes have issues with a max number of entries in a directory. That said, if he's stuck using ASP.Net (non-MVC), it's probably as good as any other suggestions out there so +1

Comment: there would only be about 15 VDs total

Answer (score 1):

No, please promise me not to create a virtual directory for each country in the world. Checkout [routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) instead. And here are some [other examples](http://www.google.com/#q=webforms+routing).

Comment: Your `other examples` is a google search. Seriously? Downvote from me, sorry guy.

Comment: @drachenstern, this is not just a google search, it is an assisted google search with proper keywords (webforms + routing) which will guide the OP to quickly find a solution to his problem.

Comment: @drachenstern, your arrogance is beginning to annoy me. Will simply ignore this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using routing or even better MVC if you haven't written the sites already. You should definitely NOT be creating multiple virtual directories - it would be a nightmare to maintain